# Extract html line from web page and paste into Excel

Tags: html, excel

I have a long list of phone numbers in Excel, and like to loop through these numbers and search on the online phone catalogue www.1881.no for corresponing name and adress. By searching the url https://www.1881.no/?query=xxxxxxxx (8 digit phone number), i get the results (name and adress). I see that the html string in line 40 ..... gives the information i need, but i have not been able to figure out how to extract it and copy the text line into the Excel sheet. Any advise?

The phone numnbers are in row A. The html string I want to extract name from and the subsequent vba code I have tried are as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Name Surname"/>


    Sub GetNamefrom1881()
'
' GetNamefrom1881 Macro
' Extract name from 1881.no based on phone numbers
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.AddressBar = True
ie.MenuBar = True
myvalue = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Value

ie.Navigate "https://www.1881.no/?query=" & myvalue

Do While ie.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

Loop

Set Doc = ie.Document
Dim metaElements
Set metaElements = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("meta")

Dim element
For Each element In metaElements
    If element.name = "og:title" Then
        Dim name
        name = element.Content
    End If
Next

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
     False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, nice to have you here. How this site works is you need to show us any code samples to show you tried anything, so we could hopefully help you with it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite new to this, but will try my best to find an example:-)